# Google Maps Android doesn't show on screen

Tags: android, apk, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create an app to Android device that use maps for Google Maps. I configured everything and when I test it on my device maps show well but when I build the APK file and upload to Play Store and download the application, the map doesn't load in any device, including the device which I test it.

Comment: Did you change the API Key?

Comment: I do not think someone will be able to help with this much details, you should put some more details in there and also you could try to make a very simple application and upload it and download and check whether it is still working

Comment: Don't you need a production key for an app downloaded from the Playstore to use Google Maps

Comment: Your api key is not correct

Comment: I use keytool to get sha1 and then use it to sign on google maps console, then I put this api key on manifest.xml and build the apk.

Comment: Solution is change in google console sha1, because the sha1 getting when running the application in debug mode is different to the production mode so if you get the sha1 that appear when you build the apk in google console and change the apikey on manifest its work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is change in google console sha1, because the sha1 getting when running the application in debug mode is different to the production mode so if you get the sha1 that appear when you build the apk in google console and change the apikey on manifest its work.